# Add buttons inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, tizen

I want to add a button in javascript code I have which stores the heart rate from Gear 2 using Tizen sdk. In my code, the main div is inserted inside javascript code. I am using the following code:

```
//HTML CODE:
<div id="chartContainer" class="chart"></div>

//JAVASCRIPT CODE:
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        fontColor: "#ccc",
        text: "Heart Rate"
    },
    backgroundColor: "#222",
    data: [{
        color: "#CD5C5C",
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: dps 
    }]
});
var lastSecond = -1;
var updateChart = function (heartrate) {
    time = new Date().getTime() - initial;
    console.log("[" + time + ", " + heartrate + "]");
    temp = heartrate;
    console.log("tempVar"+ temp);

     tizen.filesystem.resolve(
             'documents',
             function(dir){
               documentsDir = dir; dir.listFiles(onsuccess,onerror);
             }, function(e) {
               console.log("Error" + e.message);
             }, "a"
         );

    dps.push({
        x: time / 1000.0,
        y: heartrate
    });
    if (dps.length > dataLength)
    {
        dps.shift();                
    }
    var second = Math.round(time / 1000.0);
    console.log(history.length);
    if(lastSecond != second) {
        // TODO use avg heart rate instead of smapshot.
        history.push({
            x: second,
            y: heartrate
        });
        if(history.length > historyDataLength) {
            history.shift();
        }
        lastSecond = second;
    }

    if(dps.length >= dataLength) {
        chart.render();
    }
    var hrchart = "<center>" + heartrate + "bps</center><table width='100%' cellpadding=4px>";
    for(var i = history.length - historyDataLength; i >= 0 && i < history.length; i++) {
        hrchart += "<tr><td align='right' width='50%'>" + history[i].x + "s</td><td width='50%'>" + history[i].y + "bps</td></tr>";
    }
    hrchart += "</table>";
    $('#textbox').html(hrchart);
};

updateChart(0);
updateChart(250);
for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    updateChart(0);
}
```

I want to create a two buttons one for closing the application on click and one for storing data on click . How can I add those two buttons inside javascript code? Secondly is anyone familiar with "tizenhwkey" key? Which key is exactly? Thirdly I open the heartrate sensor using the following command `window.webapis.motion.start("HRM", onchangedCB)`. How can I close the heart rate sensor? Function onchangeCB is the following:

```
function onchangedCB(hrmInfo) 
{
   if(hrmInfo.heartRate > 0) {


            // add eventListener for tizenhwkey
            document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
                if(e.keyName == "back")

                    tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            });

       updateChart(hrmInfo.heartRate);
   } else {
       $('#textbox').html("No heart rate detected.");
   }
}
```

This suppose to close application when pressing back button. However gear 2 has only one button. Is this button the tiwzenhwkey? For the hrm I am using the following [code](http://aaron.jaxns.net/2014/10/accessing-the-gears-heart-rate-monitor/). For writing in file I am using:

```
function onsuccess(files) {
       var testFile = null;
       try{
          testFile = documentsDir.createFile("test.txt");
       if (testFile !== null) {
         testFile.openStream(
             "a",
             function(fs){
               fs.write(temp+"\n\n\n");
               fs.close();
             }, function(e){
               console.log("Error " + e.message);
             }, "UTF-8"
         );
       }
       }
       catch (e) { // file already exist -> append content
           testFile = documentsDir.resolve('test.txt');
            if(testFile !== null)
            {
                testFile.openStream(
                     "a",
                     function(fs){
                       fs.write(temp+"\n\n\n");
                       fs.close();
                     }, function(e){
                       console.log("Error " + e.message);
                     }, "UTF-8"
                 );
            }
        }
     }
     function onerror(error) {
       console.log("The error " + error.message + " occurred when listing the files in the selected folder");
     }
```

and

```
temp = heartrate;   
    tizen.filesystem.resolve(
            'documents',
             function(dir){
             documentsDir = dir; 
             dir.listFiles(onsuccess,onerror);
             }, function(e) {
             console.log("Error" + e.message);
             }, "a"
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Create button in JS code**

```
var b1 = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create Button
var b2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");

// Assign text to your button
b1.textContent = "Start";
b2.textContent = "Exit";

// Register click handlers to call respective functions
b1.onclick = function() {/*Code here*/};
b2.onclick = function() {/*Code here*/};

// Append them in your DOM i.e to show it on your page.
// Suppose to append it to an existing element in your page with id as "appp".
var attachTo = document.getElementById("appp");
attachTo.appendChild(b1);
attachTo.appendChild(b2);
```

**2. TIZENHWKEY**

On Gear, '**tizenhwkey**' means "**Swipe down**" gesture and "**Swipe UP**" gesture.

**Swipe Down** acts as **back** key similar to how it works on phone. **Swipe Up** acts as **menu** button similar to how it works on phone

You can use below code to handle both the gestures I mentioned above.

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e)  {
            if(e.keyName == "menu") {
            }

            if(e.keyName == "back") {
                // you need to write exit statement
                tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            }
    }
```

3. **Regarding HRM stop** - use this to stop monitoring HRM.

   webapis.motion.stop("HRM");
4. New line Issue - try this its working.

   fs.write(temp + "\n\n\n");

Comment: Yes I have code that store the hrm in a file and when I connect  gear with pc I got a file with hrm values.  Avout tizenhwkey it seems that it doesnt close the app at all when I swine down and up. Moreover I want to find a way to close the sensor device since I open my app sensor green light for hrm doesnt stop function. One last thing I am using write function to write hrm to file. However it seems that it doesnt recognize "\n". Any clue about that thing?

Comment: Have you mentioned the tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit(); statement inside the key handling. Check edited code. Initially I just wrote the code structure. I thought you will write the logic like what you want to do. Also, you havn't cleared my doubt regarding your 3rd question.

Comment: When you say Integrated you mean with galaxy device?

Comment: Integrated - It consists of the Host-side Application which runs on  Android-based Samsung mobile devices, and the Wearable-side Widget.

Standalone - It consists of only Wearable-side Widget which runs on Tizen-based Samsung Gear devices.

Comment: I run the app and I connect gear with pc just to get the file with hrm therefore stand alone.

Comment: What I am missing in your edited code? It is the same with the code I have already posted.

Comment: +1 for swineup and down you are right. As far as writing to file is concerning, is there a way to handle new line character in write function??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80020/discussion-between-srkushwaha-and-jose-ramon).

Answer (score -3):

I'm still a beginner but i know the basics on how to open a window and close it. Maybe this can help you.

```
 <button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
 <button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
var myWindow;
function openWin() { 
myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100"); 
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin(){ 
myWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: As you see the whole code of chartContainer is inside javascript. Therefore it is very convenient to write the buttons inside javascript code.